# How to Copy Image From Remote Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop

Can some one please help me to copy image from Remote Windows Desktop to my local Ubuntu 15 Desktop.

I had tried using many Paint tools, but still no luck.
I can just copy text but not the image.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using vbox to run remote windows? In that case the vbox guest additions package will allow you to create a shared folder (you can set this up in the same place as you set up your machine) or access a usb stick. Otherwise, there is the slightly less convenient way of emailing or dropboxing it.